# Center of Spin(V)

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras, spin-geometry

Picture below is from 70 of  Jost's *Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis* , How to get red line from the Lemma 2.4.1 ?

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $\text{Spin}(V)$ is subset of even part of the Clifford algebra. So if $n$ is even $a \in Cl^0(V)$ and is a real number, if $n$ is odd $a \in (Cl^0(V) \oplus Cl^n(V)) \cap \text{Spin}(V) \subset Cl^0(V)$ and is again a real number.

Comment: Really a little trick, why I can't think of this ... :)